# Can I bypass uninstall in a Visual Studio Setup Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uninstallation, setup-project

I have a Visual Studio Setup Project with a custom action on Uninstall step.

That custom action will simply display a window where the user can enter some credentials. If the credentials are correct, I want to uninstall the app. Otherwise, I want to keep the app installed (bypass the uninstall procedure).

I created a custom Installer class like in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda(v=vs.100).aspx) article.

The code adapted to my needs is the following:

```
public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
      var window = new CredentialManager();

      if(window.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          base.Uninstall(savedState);
      }
}
```

CredentialManager is my Form that I use to get the credentials from the user and decide if they are correct or not.

I am expecting to uninstall the app only if the condition is verified but it uninstalls the app anyway! Even if I leave the Uninstall method empty, it still uninstalls the app.

Do you know a way to achieve what I want?

Thank you respectfully.

Comment: I even tried base.Uninstall(null); but it doesn't do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally done it by throwing an exception when I want to cancel the uninstall step. It is a working solution, as it allows me to provide an error message to the user and rollbacks the uninstall procedure.